# Duplicate Properties coming with Cypher Query in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql

MATCH (a)-[:`PRODUCED`]->(b) RETURN a

- It's displaying 8 nodes. Its ok.
  But when i am going to return it's properties it's displaying duplicate values.

MATCH (a)-[:`PRODUCED`]->(b) RETURN a.name

- It's returning 15 rows. According to me as (a) is related with (b) 15 times and thats why its returning duplicate record but I don't need that. I need only unique 8 rows.

How will I do that or what will be the exact cypher query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, I think:

```
MATCH (a)-[:PRODUCED]->(b) RETURN DISTINCT a.name
```

or

```
MATCH (a)-[:PRODUCED]->(b) WITH a RETURN a.name
```

The former returns distinct names, which isn't good if you have multiple nodes with the same name and you want that result returned.  The later should pass on the set of distinct nodes and then return their names.  If that doesn't work, you could try `WITH DISTINCT a`

Comment: I am facing another problem.

Comment: I have two different node with same name but their dob is different. My question is how to distinct with specific properties of nodes? That is DISTINCT WITH a.id or a.dob like that.

Comment: Either `RETURN` or `WITH` will allow you to put `DISTINCT` before any expression in the clause, so if you want to pass distinct values of `id`, `name`, or `dob` you can just do `WITH/RETURN DISTINCT property`